# How to reliably stop services with systemd

Tags: systemd, debian-stretch

I want to stop service Foo and service Bar with systemctl. Service Bar `Requires: Foo` and `After: Foo`.
When I issue a command:

```
systemctl stop Foo Bar
```

Service Bar crashes on stop (this is not an issue by itself). The issue is that now in console I have:

```
Job for Foo.service canceled.
```

Why it doesn't stop Foo when Bar crashes on stop? 
How to reliably stop a set of services if some of them might crash on stop and there are some dependencies?

Moreover this behavior is not constant. Sometimes it works ok.

Comment: Figure out why it crashes and/or run the stops independent from each other?

Comment: The crash itself is not an issue. I just want to behave independetly if there are crashes or not. Yes I believe I should stop services in dependency waves. First independent, than second e.t.c. But I wonder if there's a clear explanation to this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If a crashed `Bar` service on stop is to be considered to be a "successful stop", then just let your stop command exit with success status, and everything should be fine. Otherwise systemd thinks the stop was not clean or not complete.